# Match a sound in recorded audio stream

Tags: signal-processing, audio

I have a PCM stream incoming from the microphone. I am analyzing short chunks (Java language) of it to detect short spikes in sound loudness (amplitude). I have a determined sound that plays periodically and I need to know if detected spike is in fact this sound recorded. I have the PCM for sound played, it's completely determined.

I have no clue where to start, should I perform some comparison in time domain or frequency domain? Would be great if someone could give me some insight on how this is done and where should I dig.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to compare an incoming set of pulses to a references set of pulses. Cross-correlation is probably what you want to use. You may need to precondition your data first, eg create an envelope instead of using raw data, or the cross-correlation may fail unless the match is perfect.

Comment: Thank you. I will research that. The match cannot be perfect because one sound is the "pure sound" and another one is the same on recorded on a (fairly low quality) microphone.

Comment: Since no one else suggested anything else and from what I digged this seems as a way to go, I am marking this as an accepted offer. Thank you.